# I have two models in MongooseDB, how do I update the two at once using Node.js and React.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two models named user and post in my Mongoose database. I will like that when I update the user model, it reflects on the post model. For instance, I updated my username from the user model, I would like that update to take effect on the post model as well. I am using Node.js and React.

[image]

**here is my code on Node.js for the user model**

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) =>{
if(req.body.userId === req.params.id){//we checked if the user id matched
 if(req.body.password){
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        }
        try{
       const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
            
               $set: req.body,
              
               
           }, {new: true}); 
            //findbyidandupdate is an inbuilt method
    
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser)
       
    } catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err) //this handles the error if there is one from the server
    }
    } else{
    res.status(401).json("You can only update your account!")
   }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to have user information attached with each post and when the user data is modified, the changes should reflect on subsequent requests for post data as well.

The functionality you are looking for is mongoose `refs` and `populate`.
These allow you to have reference to documents in a document.
In your case, we want a `ref` to a user document inside a post document.

So the `schema` for `Post` model could look like this:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.schema({
  ...
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } // Here 'User' is the name of the UserModel
  ...
})
```

Now each post will contain a reference of a user.
The data that is being saved on each post doc as the `user` property is the `_id` of a user doc (not the complete document). So you can update the user docs without worrying about how it's going to affect the posts.

For retrieving the user information each time you retreive a post, you need to `populate` the post doc.

```
const post = await Post.
  findOne(...).
  populate('user').exec()
```

More information: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your effort to help me on this. Please can you give me the opportunity to ask you further questions about this steps privately via this platform?

Comment: Sure @kinhs here's my github profile https://github.com/akshay-nm with contact details. Feel free to reachout. I don't know if you can ask questions privately on stackoverflow. But I'd be happy to help.